# I have and indexed array that looks like this

Tags: drupal-8, php-7.1

`$values[0]['myname']['myheight']['height'];`

`$values[1]['myname']['myheight']['height'];`

`$values[2]['myname']['myheight']['height'];`

`$values[3]['myname']['myheight']['height'];`

I want to loop through the array to check 'height' and skip through the other values if the are set especially the first key in my $values array.
I tried something like

```
$values[$key];

if (is_numeric($key) ) {
do this
}
```

but this doesn't seem to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
  if(isset($val['myname']['myheight']['height'])){
    #do this
  }
}
```